# Getting rid of padding at the bottom of bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot seem to get rid of the pesky white space between my page titles and my bootstrap navbar.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9aorkwwd/

Main CSS:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #1a1a1a;
    }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
.navbar-static-top {
  min-height: 100px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
#page-title {
  background-color: #FF9900;
}
```

I generated the CSS for the navbar using http://twbscolor.smarchal.com/, as I do not know much about customizing bootstrap. So far, I've tried changing the different pixel heights etc. in the CSS, but nothing has worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is the "Hello!" bar is an `H1` which contains a top margin as well.

If you want to see it fixed, add:

```
margin-bottom: 0;
```

to your `navbar-default` and

```
style="margin-top: 0"
```

to your `H1`

Comment: Thanks, how would I go on about removing the margin in <h1> ?

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
.navbar-default {
background-color: #000000;
border-color: #1a1a1a;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
h1{
margin-top:0;
}
```

if You don't Want to tamper with the default setting Use this

```
#page-title {
background-color: #FF9900;
position: relative;
top: -20px;
}
```